JSDoc duplicate documentation of classes
I'm using JSDoc and better-docs to document my TypeScript code. I encounter two not that fatal but very annoying problems. One of them is I get this weird double documentation that I will try my best to explain.
In my project I have documented many interfaces and
classes. To better visualize the documentation I use the @category tag provided by better-docs. This makes the side navigation to look something like this:
├Components/
│   ├── Classes
│   ├── Activity
│   ├── ActivityView
│   ├── Applet
│   ├── BarChart
│   ├── BarClusteredChart
│   ├── BarScoredMissingChart
│   ├── BarStackedChart
│   ├── etc
└Interfaces/
    ├── BuilderDocumentTreeConfig
    ├── BuilderDocumentViewConfig
    ├── BuilderPropertyGridConfig
    ├── BuilderToolboxConfig
    └── DataProjectionConfig

Right above it though I get the result of this weird double documentation:
├── Classes/
│   ├── Activity
│   ├── Base
│   ├── Input
│   ├── ActivityView
│   ├── Base
│   ├── Applet
│   ├── Document
│   ├── BarChart
│   ├── Base
│   ├── BarClusteredChart
│   ├── Base
│   ├── BarScoredMissingChart
│   ├── Base
│   ├── BarStackedChart
│   ├── Base
│   ├── BarThinBarsChart
│   ├── Base
│   ├── Base
│   ├── etc

(The Base class is being extended by the other classes.)

This is the Activity class in the duplicated navigation*.
This is the Activity class in the proper "Components"-category navigation.
Here is my jsdoc.json:

{
    "source": {
        "include": [
            "packages/components"
        ],
        "includePattern": ".+\\.ts$",
        "exclude": [
            "packages/components/DataProjection/node_modules",
            "packages/libs/Popper/node_modules",
            "packages/libs/Charts/node_modules"
        ],
        "excludePattern": "(^|\\/|\\\\)_."
    },
    "plugins": [
        "node_modules/better-docs/typescript",
        "node_modules/better-docs/category"
    ],
    "opts": {
        "destination": "./docs/",
        "recurse": true,
        "template": "node_modules/better-docs",
        "readme": "README.md",
        "verbose": true
    },
    "templates": {
        "cleverLinks": false,
        "monospaceLinks": false,
        "search": true,
        "default": {
            "outputSourceFiles": true
        },
        "better-docs": {
            "name": "VELOCITY-UI",
            "title": "VELOCITY-UI",
            "hideGenerator": true
        },
        "staticFiles": {
            "include": [
                "./static"
            ]
        }
    }
}

I have looked up the problem on this issue but the proposed solution is not a possibility for me.
So as you can see it's a big big mess. I'm looking for a way to completely remove the second messed up navigation or at the very least get rid of all the duplication.
